# Clearing form issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reset

I am having problems clearing my form with Javascript/jQuery

Here is how my form is defined - all tags are closed how they should be in the order they should be

```
<form id="eventpostform" name="eventpostform" method="post" action="post">
    <table cellspacing="5px" style="margin-top: 10px;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="180px">Event Name:</td>
            <td width="210px"><a class="param_submit" style="width:86px;padding:6px 5px;margin-left:16px;" alt="" onclick="clearform();">Clear Form</a></td>
```

I've tried the following but with no luck:

```
$('#eventpostform').clearForm();
$('#eventpostform').resetForm();
$('#eventpostform').reset();
document.getElementById("eventpostform").reset();
```

the top 2 just do nothing, the other two display the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reset' of null"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear using reset method on the the form object not the controls in form. You will have to clear individual html element but their method, e.g. to cleart textbox you can set its value to `''` or some value.

To reset all controls in form

```
document.getElementById("eventpostform").reset();
```

To clear individual control

```
document.getElementById("textboxId").value = '';
```

Using jQuery

```
$('#id').val('');
```

Comment: Long winded - but if it does the job... I'm in! Thank you!

Comment: `$('[name=event_name]').val("");` did it like that... works well enough for me!

Comment: Thats good you use attribute selector for name instead of id, great job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#eventpostform')[0].reset();
```

Comment: Are you sure you're loading jQuery?